# $SF_1 (f_1 + f_2) = SF_1(f_1) + SF_1(f_2)$

Tags: homological-algebra

Let F be a right exact functor. Prove

$SF_1 (f_1 + f_2) = SF_1(f_1) + SF_1(f_2)$ where $f_1, f_2 :M \rightarrow M'$.

I have just started reading homological algebra so please help me to solve this one.

Comment: Could you say what $S$ is?

Comment: $SF_1$ is the satelite functor